# Fix error with route url in Asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I have this datamodel: [image]
so one Project has many Milestones.
What I did is this: when I go to the detail of a specific Project, I can add/create Milestones for it, like in the picture: [image]
When I click "Create Milestone" I navigate to the View where I can create the milestone for this specific Project, when I click save, it will automatically be saved for this project. Here the HttpPost method:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateMilestone([Bind(Include = "Name,Description,FromDate,DueDate,Finished,ProjectID")] Milestone milestone, int? id)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var forProject = db.Projects.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (forProject != null)
            {
                milestone.Project = forProject;
                db.Milestones.Add(milestone);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", forProject);
            }
            else
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return View(milestone);
        }
    }
```

Here is a screenshot of the CreateMilestone View, and focus on the url (it's localhost:xxxxx/Projects/CreateMilestone/3002). The id parameter in the CreateMilestone method is for the Project ID, and in the url the id (3002) is also for the project.
[image]

I'm trying to make the app to navigate to the Details view of that specific Project I just added a milestone, which I do actually!
And as you see it works: 
[image]

But: look at the url! Instead of being localhost:xxxxx/Projects/Details/3002 it is: http://localhost:55623/Projects/Details/3002?Milestones=System.Collections.Generic.HashSet%601%5BTheProjectManager.Models.Milestone%5D&Users=System.Collections.Generic.HashSet%601%5BTheProjectManager.Models.ApplicationUser%5D&ProjectName=Testing&Description=Testing%20data

So, how can I make the url be like: localhost:xxxxx/Projects/Details/3002 when I navigate to the details view after adding a new milestone?

UPDATE: 
the Get Details:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
        if (project == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(project);
    }
```

and the Get CreateMilestone:

```
public ActionResult CreateMilestone(int? id)
    {
        var forProject = db.Projects.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (forProject != null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code for the GET verb

Comment: More code & text, fewer pictures.

Comment: @mparnisari updated the question with get Details and get CreateMilestone methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `return RedirectToAction("Details",forProject);`
try this `return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = id });`

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
return RedirectToAction("Details", forProject);
```

you are redirecting to `Details` action and as parameter you send "Project" object which is serialized to query string. Instead of full object you can use only `id`. But you also need to change `Details` action to accept int as parameter instead of `Project` class

Comment: this is the Details method: public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Project project = db.Projects.Find(id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(project);
        }